# Creating a custom line with canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, image-resizing

I would like to use a 4x4 pixel bitmap (another brick in the wall) to draw a line, the line can start/stop anywhere and go in any direction.

I am trying something like the following :

```
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick);
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float newWidth = Math.abs(line.startX - line.stopX);
    float newHeight = Math.abs(line.startY - line.stopY);
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, (int)line.startX,(int)line.startY, width, height, matrix, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, m, paint);
```

I realise that this is a resize, rather than drawing the .bmp sequentially. Also it throws errors `x + width must be <= bitmap.width()`

Does anyone have any suggestions of a technique to use here ?

Comment: Are you looking to draw sequentially with the tightest packing that prevents overlap, or just pattern the bitmap at some constant positional delta?

Comment: Looking to draw without overlap ... I can compute the equation of the line I want to draw `Y=MX+C` and account for the vertical cases

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, **the simplest technique to use would be computing an X increment value and a Y increment value**. The nature of this calculation will depend on whether you want closely packed bitmaps or overlapping:

**For overlap, this should be a simple slope calculation** (don't forget the zero/infinity slope edge cases!).

**For close packing, determine the close packed direction** (X or Y) by comparing the slope the line to the slope of a line drawn on the image diagonal. If the line is steeper than the image diagonal, you need Y close-packing. In the alternate situation, you need X close-packing.

**Then, compute the increment values**. The increment value in the close packed axis (if one is needed) will be the dimension of the bitmap along that axis. The increment value in the other axis will be a simple linear function of the slope of the line and the close packed increment.

Once you have your increment values, **iteratively draw the bitmap to the canvas**, starting the the line start location, and incrementing the draw location each iteration. **Stop iterating when your increment causes either value to overshoot the line end**. In computing the increment and when checking for the end of the line, you'll have to account for the fact that the lines coordinates might go from a low number to a high number, or from a high number to a low number.

You might also decide that you don't always want to start drawing at the start point, and you instead want to "center" your line such that the start and end images are equidistant at their centers from the actual endpoints. In this case, you'll have to compute a different starting point, but it should involve fairly simple math.

Comment: Sounds very logical, which forms of the `canvas.drawBitmap` is best suited ?

Comment: I followed your suggestion : made 3 case, vertical, horizontal and diagonal lines and incremented along the line either X, Y or X & Y . Works very well !

Comment: @avrono Glad to see you figured out the correct contract of drawBitmap. If this answered your question, can you mark it as an answer? This will credit my reputation and make it easier for other users who are experiencing the same issue to find the answer.